Pagination for nested accordion in AngularJS
Could someone assist me with adding pagination within an accordion? I'd really appreciate the help!
HTML Code:
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
      <div class="accordion-item" ng-repeat="item in pgmg" ng-class="{'active': item.isOpen}">
        <div class="accordion-header" ng-click="toggle(item)">
          <p>{{item.automationState}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-content" ng-show="item.isOpen">
          <table class='table table-striped' border='1'>
            <thead class='thead-dark'>
              <tr>
                <th>Migration context</th>
                <th>CHG number</th>
                <th>Instance Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="pgmgObj in getPagingData(item)">
                <td>{{pgmgObj.migrationContext}}</td>
                <td>{{pgmgObj.chg}}</td>
                <td>{{pgmgObj.instanceName}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <uib-pagination total-items="item.totalItems" ng-model="item.currentPage" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-change="updatePage(item)"></uib-pagination>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

JavaScript Code:
// Define the AngularJS module and controller
angular.module('simpleApp', [])
  .controller('SimpleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.pgmg = [];
    
    // Function to toggle accordion item open/closed state
    $scope.toggle = function(item) {
        item.isOpen = !item.isOpen;
    };
  
     $scope.itemsPerPage = 5;
       // Pagination function for each accordion item
    $scope.getPagingData = function(item) {
    let start = (item.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage;
    let end = start + $scope.itemsPerPage;
    return item.details.slice(start, end);
  };

  // Update the current page data for each item
  $scope.updatePage = function(item) {
    item.totalItems = item.details.length;
  };
  
  });


Each item in $scope.pgmg has its own currentPage and totalItems properties.
The getPagingData function takes item as an argument to provide data for the specific accordion item's page.
Each uib-pagination directive is bound to item.currentPage and calls updatePage on page change, which updates the paginated data for that specific item.

[code] https://plnkr.co/edit/Zz1s2uMwTKCAvQXd?preview
Issue:
I can restrict the number of items per page in the accordion, but the issue is that the navigation buttons are not visible within the accordion.

you can maybe share a plunkr like https://plnkr.co/edit/ZXUmDopAHHVp9frj?preview

@user2748161 Please explain the problem you are facing implementing it, there seems to be no code related to pagination., jiust displaying tables is present

@NarenMurali If you see Javascript code there is a function called getPaginatedData and in HTML I am calling using ng-repeat="pgmgObj in getPaginatedData(item)

@cmgchess here is the link [link] (https://plnkr.co/edit/Zz1s2uMwTKCAvQXd?preview)
